# Multi-Friend-Invite on my website?

Tags: fbml, xfbml, invite

I have a website and users who have registered on my site by using FBConnect to login.
As they're authenticated with my app I have access to their profile from PHP and from JS.
I'm trying to render the multi-friend-invite with FBML and nothing is happening.

I'm trying to build a "refer your friends" page and render a multi-friend-invite widget on our webpage.

Can someone give me some advice? The FBML i'm using is not being modified in the DOM at all.
I've tried a direct FB.XFBML.parse() call on the surrounding <div> and it's still doing nothing.

Help?

Comment: FBML is in the process of [being depricated](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/).. That means that at some stage in the near future it will stop working all together.. You should not use it... Instead, why dont you read up on the [javascript sdk](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) - It can provide you with the same functionality of friend invites as [mentioned here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/)...

Good luck!

Comment: @lix thanks for the information. So is it possible to render the 'invite friends' component within the FB.ui() dialog box?

Comment: yea - it looks something like this :     FB.ui({method: 'apprequests', message: 'come see my application!'});

Comment: I'm unable to render any FB.ui() calls. Chrome is complaining about cross-domain stuff and just stops execution. I see i might need something like an xd_receive file to stop this? but I'm not sure what to put in it.